# Drupal exposed filter not displaying children

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views

Please refer the image [image: image-1]

when select the child category it shows "searchfilter?field_category_tid=5"

[image: image-2]

but when I select the parent it shows nothing "searchfilter?field_category_tid=4"

[image: image-3]

I know this can be solved by creating contextual filters or some sort of relationship setting. But I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: In settings of exposed filter category , you can choose depth of your taxonomy ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using grouped filters. When configuring the field in the **Filter type to expose** chose grouped filters
[image: configure field]

Then you can enter the parent name and all the children to be filtered.
Also you can enter the child name and only 1 field (the child ) to be filtered.

[image: like this]

Comment: I think this is too much work if your list is too long. I believe there should be a easy way to achieve this

Comment: I had a too long list too :) this way allows you to do like 20 options I think, so in order not to change the core files, I decided to do a custom module for that view and added the options manually. But if you find a shorter way please share it ^_^